# Renaming a folder changes file location into \\?\D:User... and I cant open it

Tags: windows

I have a folder *Work* which contains some word and jpeg files. After renaming the folder *Work* into *2021 Work* I can't access file content anymore. Word (or image viewing software) opens but doesn't show anything. When I right click the file it says that the Location is `\\?\D:\User\Admin\Desktop`.
I am certain that if I can remove this `\\?\` that the files would open.

When I move a file in any other folder - it opens normally, if I rename it back to Work - it opens normally.

What is going on?

Comment: Your question is unreadable. You might try to use source code format for showing the weird values (which you can do, either using backticks or either by starting your line with four spaces).

Comment: The problem was with the length of the path. I am not 100% certain, but I am fairly confident this is the case. When I renamed the folder I used a really long name for both the folder and a file I had. By moving it to Desktop, I've saved cca. 100 characters...